# How to add a reference Bing Maps in a Windows Phone 8

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, bing-maps

I have been trying to add a Bing Maps reference to my project but I can't find a reference when searching in the reference manage in Visual Studio 2013.I have installed the SDK in the extensions and updates window but still not able to get a reference to it.
Is there a step I may be missing in adding maps to the project?
I already add the sdk for win8 bing map JavaScript, but its not work with WP8.

Or if its possible, another solution to use maps in WP8 with javascript.
I use VS2013 update 2 RC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows phone 8 does not use Bing maps anymore, it used Maps offering based on here maps: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207045%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

I would also have additional examples for it available at the [github](https://github.com/nokia-developer/maps-samples)

Comment: ok I understand, but My work using html5 and I need to use geolocalisation and routes, any suggestion?

Comment: Then you should check any javascrpt based offering. Such as Google maps or Here maps. Though check their usage rules to see how they could be used in mobiles and if there is any limitations for usage in general

Comment: I did and its not work, all problem about undifined microsoft or nokia

Comment: Basically, what I meant is that since you are using HTML code, you would simply add the APIs there as you would in any webpage, and then use what ever you have used for showing the page.

Comment: that's the problem, how to add API, I use Google Map API, but it's not working, SO I will give up, I will this feature only with win8